# last views in scroll view is not visible in my tab acticity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

Hi i am using tab activity.In My fragment i am displaying some details with textview.i am using scroll view to view my textview.But the last two textview in my layout is not visible inside my scroll view.how to solve this please help me.my xml code is `

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/imagelay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="230dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="175dp"
                    android:layout_height="151dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="169dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/iconpo" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imagelay"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="6dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Cavin K"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Who am i" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="KAVIN PRABU M" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Date of birth" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"

                    android:text="27.06.1995" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Father's Name" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"

                    android:text="Mohandass A" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Mother's Name" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"

                    android:text="Sumathy R.V" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Nationality" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Indian" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Marital Status" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Indian" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Address" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="158 B,Souknkll"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your layout to this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="200dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/imagelay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="230dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="175dp"
                    android:layout_height="151dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="169dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/iconpo" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imagelay"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="6dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Cavin K"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Who am i" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="KAVIN PRABU M" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Date of birth" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"

                    android:text="27.06.1995" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Father's Name" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"

                    android:text="Mohandass A" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Mother's Name" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"

                    android:text="Sumathy R.V" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Nationality" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Indian" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Marital Status" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Indian" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Address" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    style="@style/SmallText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="158 B,Souknkll"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ,thanks for your reply...still its not showing my last two textview.I am using this fragment in my tab activity.

Comment: ,thanks a lot..its working for me...thanks a lot...what mistake i had done?can u please tel me that i will rectify..

Comment: Check the LinearLayout just below the ScrollView. I have added a padding of 200dp. If you dont give a suitable padding then the scrollView doesn't scroll up fully and a part of it remains under the screen. Thus you should always give a good amount of padding while using scrollView. And do change the value of the padding as per your need.

Comment: And please do mark my answer as correct if I could help you.

Comment: Its only showing an upvote. Please mark the tick on the left hand side of the answer so that it turns green. That will mark the answer as correct.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This an addition to the answer given by Abhiriya Roy.
Add padding programmatically like below

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23) {
        float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int dpAsPixels = (int) (60 * scale + 0.5f);
        rlMain.setPadding(0, 0, 0, dpAsPixels);
    }

rlMain is my Relative Layout
```

You not need to give extra padding for sdk version 23 if you do that it will give extra space.